# Apache Camel SNMP Component

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, apache-camel, snmp4j

currently I am working on a project where I receive OPC UA data and send them via SNMP to a PRTG monitoring system. I already created the routes between OPC UA datapoints and a SNMP client (with an unique OID). The problem here is the connection to the PRTG monitoring system. When I start the connection I get a NullPointer Exception on the the SnmpTrapProducer. It seems like I cannot create a trap of type PDU in SNMPTrapProducer.java

I figured out that the PDU trap that is created in SnmpTrapProducer.process(Exchange exchange) returns the NullPointerException(you can see the parts of the class in the picture). I tried different approaches like changing message body types or different ports as well as on ip addresses. But I still get the NullPointerException.

What do I have to configure, so the trap doesn't return a NullPointer Exception?

[Image of parts of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/es6AN.png)

**SnmpTrapProducer.java**

```
...
PDU trap = exchange.getIn().getBody(PDU.class);

trap.setErrorIndex(0);
trap.setErrorStatus(0);
trap.setMaxRepetitions(0);
...
```

The following code is the configuration of the Camel Route

```
from("milo-client:opc.tcp://"
                + OpcConfiguration.getIpAdress() + ":"
                + OpcConfiguration.getPort()
                + "?node=RAW(" + snmpOidDataStructure.getOpcDataStructure().getNodeId() + ")&allowedSecurityPolicies=None")
                .to("stream:out")
                .to("snmp://10.3.248.12:5700?protocol=udp&type=TRAP&snmpVersion=1&oids=" + snmpOidDataStructure.getOid());
```

The message body from the OPC component looks like that:

```
{value=Variant{value=[LocalizedText{text=CP, locale=de}, LocalizedText{text=Video, locale=de}, LocalizedText{text=Notfallsäule, locale=de}, LocalizedText{text=CP Notruf 2 [Gleis 2], locale=de}, LocalizedText{text=, locale=de}]}, status=StatusCode{name=Good, value=0x00000000, quality=good}, sourceTime=DateTime{utcTime=131999719975360000, javaDate=Wed Apr 17 12:53:17 CEST 2019}, serverTime=DateTime{utcTime=132164793099138549, javaDate=Fri Oct 25 14:15:09 CEST 2019}}
```

Error Message:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at org.apache.camel.component.snmp.SnmpTrapProducer.process(SnmpTrapProducer.java:112) ~[Schnittstellenadapter-1.0-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:61) ~[Schnittstellenadapter-1.0-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor.process(SendProcessor.java:148) ~[Schnittstellenadapter-1.0-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler.process(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:548) ~[Schnittstellenadapter-1.0-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201) [Schnittstellenadapter-1.0-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:138) [Schnittstellenadapter-1.0-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.Pipeline.process(Pipeline.java:101) [Schnittstellenadapter-1.0-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.CamelInternalProcessor.process(CamelInternalProcessor.java:201) [Schnittstellenadapter-1.0-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:97) [Schnittstellenadapter-1.0-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.apache.camel.component.milo.client.MiloClientConsumer.handleValueUpdate(MiloClientConsumer.java:78) [Schnittstellenadapter-1.0-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.eclipse.milo.opcua.sdk.client.subscriptions.OpcUaMonitoredItem.lambda$setValueConsumer$0(OpcUaMonitoredItem.java:133) ~[Schnittstellenadapter-1.0-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.eclipse.milo.opcua.sdk.client.subscriptions.OpcUaMonitoredItem.onValueArrived(OpcUaMonitoredItem.java:191) ~[Schnittstellenadapter-1.0-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.eclipse.milo.opcua.sdk.client.subscriptions.OpcUaSubscriptionManager.lambda$null$39(OpcUaSubscriptionManager.java:700) ~[Schnittstellenadapter-1.0-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.eclipse.milo.opcua.stack.core.util.ExecutionQueue$PollAndExecute.run(ExecutionQueue.java:107) ~[Schnittstellenadapter-1.0-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_221]
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: Welcome to SO! OK, first of all: never post images of code. That is as useful for people wanting to help you as a brick is for a swimming aid. Second: do not just post code snippets you _think_ might be the reason. You might want to read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), which enhances the probability for getting a useful answer _drastically_. You might find [ESR](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eric_S._Raymond)'s excellent essay [How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) helpful, too, despite it's harsh title.

Comment: Please provide your [SNMP4J](https://www.snmp4j.org) dependency configuration (maven/gradle).

Comment: What is the Apache Camel [version](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.apache.camel/camel) you use?

Comment: apache camel version: 2.25.0
the camel snmp component provides the snmp4j dependency. it is using snmp4j version 3.2.2

Answer (score 0):

The class `SnmpTrapProducer` throws a NPE because the **message body seems to be empty**.

As your picture shows, the problem is that the **variable `trap` stays `null`**. It should become an object on this line.

```
PDU trap = exchange.getIn().getBody(PDU.class);
```

The line gets the message body content and it wants it to be an instance of `org.snmp4j.PDU`.

Unfortunately you don't show the code that populates the message body, but **I assume the message body is simply empty**.

Try to log out the message body in your route before you pass it on to the SNMP component

```
 .log("Message body: ${body}")
```

The other option would be that the message body is of another type than `org.snmp4j.PDU`, but I think then it would throw a `TypeConversionException`.

Comment: First of all, thank you for help!
You are totally right about the problem. The thing is that the SNMPTrapProducer is a class of the apache camel snmp component that I can't edit. I just call the component with a string of parameters where I have no option to change specific things like the pdu message body

Comment: Have you checked the unittests of Camel SNMP? In general the Camel unittests are a great source of how to use a component. Perhaps you will find how the tests pass data to the `SnmpTrapProducer` and adapt it to your case.

Comment: I checked that too, but didn't get any results. They use the component the same as I do. I also tried different approaches with url settings but they make no difference - always get a null pointer exception in the same line

Comment: It is impossible to dig deeper because your question does not contain the code where the message that results in a NPE is created. We can observe that the message cannot be converted to a PDU. Probably the conversion expects something else than the message body contains.

Comment: I added the camel route where I call the snmp route. Hope that helps... Do I have to configure anything else than the route? Where should I configure the message body?

Comment: I receive the boolean datapoints via opc, hash them to a unique OID and send them to a PRTG monitoring system

Comment: Great, according to the route you pass on as message body what you receive. Can you dump out the message body in the route and check if it is empty? I added a logging statement to add to the route in my answer.

Comment: I added the log to my route and updated my post with the message body dump!

Comment: One last Camel route thing: I just spotted the `to("stream:out")` in your route that sends the message body to `System.out`. Can you remove the log-statement again and also `.to("stream:out")` (so that only `from` and `to` remains) and run another test? Because if the route input is a stream and it is "used" in the route, the stream is "empty" afterwards.

Comment: If this is not the problem, the message body is probably just not "compatible" with the `PDU` class. You can start to test the logged message body against the [snmp4j library](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/snmp4j). Camel tries to cast the logged string directly into a `PDU` instance. You can do the same in a test class. If you use the lib directly, perhaps you get some error messages to figure out what is the problem. If you are able to find the problems in the received string, you could insert a converter into the route that translates the received string into one that works with PDU.

Comment: I’m writing as colleague of Stefan Lederer. Unfortunately, the project Stefan was working on will be put on hold. Thank you very much for your answers. We will try your solution as soon as we can continue with the project.